# Twitter Card Image not appearing on Gatsby

Tags: twitter, gatsby

I've got an older Gatsby instance and I'm trying to get the Twitter large card to appear for my blog posts.

**What do I see?**

[image]

**What have I tried?**

I've met the following criteria:

1. Social links need to have a domain + protocol
2. Meta tags need to render without JS
3. Meta tags need need to be in the first couple kbs - https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/22908
4. I'm not breaking the head with invalid elements
5. The image ratio is approximately right 1200*600 - 2:1

My posts render on FB & LinkedIn, it's just Twitter which is the issue. Technically the problem is inconsistent (two old blog posts work, the two new ones fail I think that's just because the old ones are cached).

[image]

I used the following Gatsby code in my gatsby-ssr.js to rejig the header so that meta tags appear first to ensure that the links would be picked up in the first couple bytes.

```
export const onRenderBody = (
    { setHeadComponents, setHtmlAttributes, setBodyAttributes },
    pluginOptions
) => {
    const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
    setHtmlAttributes(helmet.htmlAttributes.toComponent());
    setBodyAttributes(helmet.bodyAttributes.toComponent());
    setHeadComponents([
        helmet.title.toComponent(),
        helmet.link.toComponent(),
        helmet.meta.toComponent(),
        helmet.noscript.toComponent(),
        helmet.script.toComponent(),
        helmet.style.toComponent()
    ]);
};

export const onPreRenderHTML = ({
    getHeadComponents,
    replaceHeadComponents
}) => {
    const headComponents = getHeadComponents();

    headComponents.sort((x, y) => {
        if (x.props && x.props["data-react-helmet"]) {
            return -1;
        } else if (y.props && y.props["data-react-helmet"]) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    replaceHeadComponents(headComponents);
};
```

**What now?**

What else should I look at? I'm totally baffled.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I tried many ways but still can't fix this. Then I found out that it may be a network problem because if you just publish this content it will be displayed normally on your twitter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).